Is authorization code flow with public client secret equivalent to implicit flow?
I want my single-page web application to log in to Jira via the OAuth implicit flow. However, Jira only offers the authorization code flow.
Assume I have determined that the implicit flow is secure enough for my needs and I cannot build a backend.
If I add the client secret to my client bundle (exposing it publicly), isn't that functionally equivalent to using the implicit flow?
Implicit flow:

Click "Log in with Jira" in my application
Redirect to Jira
Log in on Jira
Redirect back with access token

Authorization code flow:

Click "Log in with Jira" in my application
Redirect to Jira
Log in on Jira
Redirect back with authorization code
Browser exchanges authorization code for access token using the public client secret

If the client secret is public, anyone can exchange the authorization code for the access token after step 4, but I don't mind, because in the implicit flow my application would have the access token already.

Is this any less safe than the implicit flow?
Can the client secret be used for more things than exchanging the authorization code for an access token?
What can an attacker do with a leaked client secret that they couldn't already do in the implicit flow?

Edit:
I am not looking for an explanation of how OAuth works. I just want an answer to the question below:
Website A

Uses authorization code flow
Exposes the client secret in its frontend

Website B

Uses implicit flow

My only question:
Is website A more vulnerable than website B and why?

The answer is "it depends" - see oAuth BCP for details. Is it possible to mitigate various risks for implicit grant? Sure. But it would be a lot safer to use authorization code flow out of the box, it doesn't have these risks embedded in the protocol.

The implicit flow only existed because the spec was written before CORS was introduced and implemented by major browsers. That meant that your SPA at myAwesomeSPA.com couldn't directly send HTTP requests to an authorization server at another domain such as accounts.google.com. the only way of communication was through browser redirects. this is why the access_token had to be sent as a query param to the callback URL.
Once CORS was introduced, there was no need to expose the access_token in the URL and instead, a random code is going to be returned in the URL which your SPA can exchange for an access_token via a direct HTTP POST request. This makes the process more secure because this random code is valid for very little time (usually less than a minute) and can only be used once. So there is no reason whatsoever to use this "implicit flow" anymore.
Now back to your question. it seems to me that you are assuming that to use the authorization code flow, you need to have a client_secret. this is not true. you can use that flow with public clients without client_secret. The authorization code flow as the name suggests is all about this intermediate step of getting a code and exchanging it for an access_token as opposed to directly receiving the access_token directly in the callback redirect.
So there is no reason to use a client_secret for a public client. and there is no reason to use the implicit flow. For public clients you should always use the authorization code flow + Proof key for code exchange (PKCE). which is what most libraries do by default. For more info see: OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps

Edit: I thought it was obvious but yes the website that exposes the secret will be "more vulnerable" (exposes more attack surface) than the one that uses the implicit flow. The implicit flow is only slightly worse at exposing short-lived access tokens whose access level is limited to what the user can access than the authorization code flow (For SPAs). Exposing the client secret on the other hand exposes you to a different level of threats. anyone would be able to impersonate your client application. anyone would be able to introspect, revoke, and generate tokens (via client credentials). You open yourself to service abuse as well. If you are using a managed service in the cloud, a request containing the correct client_id and client_secret is a valid request and you will be billed for it.

The answer from @adel provides the recommended flow you should use, yet you cannot due to integrating directly with Jira, which does not support it.
THE OAUTH WAY
If you want to use a JavaScript only app it should work like this:

SPA uses code flow + PKCE
SPA redirects to its authorization server (AS)
AS runs another code flow to Jira's identity provider (IDP) and provides the required client secret
Jira issues tokens to your AS
AS issues tokens to your SPA, and can include a Jira access token as a claim in the SPA's own access token
Your SPA can securely call both Jira and its own APIs

THREATS
Your solution is marginally better than the implicit flow, since it does not expose access tokens so easily. Yet it would also fail security reviews in an obvious way, since it cannot use PKCE and does not manage the client secret correctly.
To produce a comparison you would need to go through the sections of the OAuth Threat Model and make two lists of vulnerabilities. I don't think anyone on SO is going to want to do that work for you, to compare two flows that should never be used.
WHAT TO DO?
I would recommend a short term action of routing token requests via a small backend component that attaches the client secret. Eg an AWS serverless lambda. At least then you are running a basically secure flow, yet it will still be vulnerable to threats that PKCE protects against.

Thanks for your response. I understand how OAuth works and I know how to build my own authorization server that handles the exchange of authorization code for an access token. My question is of theoretical nature. I am just trying to understand if knowing the client secret allows an attacker to do something that is not already possible with an app using the implicit flow. Imagine application A that uses the authorization code flow with an exposed client secret in the frontend and application B that uses the implicit flow. Is application A more vulnerable than application B?

If someone gets access to your client secret, it basically means he can acquire access token as an application, so for example, if your application has permissions to change any sensitive details, this access token allows anyone to be able to do so. Using Client Credentials flow basically gives access token in return for application-name and client-secret.
